# Where are examples of : Angular.js + RESTful API + click-to-edit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, clicktoedit

I am trying to write something slightly more than a web front-end to edit tables in a relational database.  (I have some foreign keys and would like to make drop-downs with the corresponding name in the second table which contains the key.)  I have created a RESTful API to the database using express.

Where would I find an example of a click-to-edit user interface like a DataGrid, but with the data read and written using a RESTful API instead of stored in variables?

If I use a $resource to access the RESTful API, how do I hook up dirty-checking to the $resource so that if the user edits text in the browser then the result gets saved to the database, and if the database gets changed by a second user then the display of the first user gets updated?  Is there a way to tell angular.js to do this for me?

Am I trying to do this in the wrong way?  I am experienced at programming but relatively new to angular.js.

If this is already discussed elsewhere then pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this answer for an example of form submission as well as resource communication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440964/angularjs-jquery-ajax-form-submission-equivalent/29441219#29441219

Comment: This is an example of communicating the change from the browser to the database: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822252/AngularJS-Backend-Solution-ng-grid-with-a-Simple-R